# Confusion on Room Auto Migration with NOT NULL column but no defalut value

Tags: kotlin, android-sqlite, android-room

## Short Version

After updating Android-Room version from 2.2.x to 2.4.x, I decide to use auto-migration feature to help me write less code. So I want to deprecate all migration written manually and use auto-migration instead. But I have got an error when using auto-migration:

```kotlin
// Compile Time Error: 
// New NOT NULL column'height' added with no default value specified. 
// Please specify the default value using @ColumnInfo.

@ColumnInfo(name = "height")
val height: Long = 0L
```

Even if I have specify default value by this way, but still get same error:

```kotlin
@ColumnInfo(name = "height", defaultValue = "0")
val height: Long = 0L
```

What wrong with my code and how can I fix this error?

## Long Version

I have two version database:

**Version 1**

```kotlin
@Entity(tableName = "user")
data class User(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    val id: Long = 0L,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    val name: String = ""
)

@Database(
    entities = [User::class],
    version = 1
)
abstract class UserDB : RoomDatabase()
```

then at version 2 I add a column which name is 'height' in user table:

**Version 2**

```kotlin
@Entity(tableName = "user")
data class User(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    val id: Long = 0L,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    val name: String = "",
    @Column(name = "height")
    val height: Long = 0L
)

@Database(
    entities = [User::class],
    version = 2
)
abstract class UserDB : RoomDatabase() {
    object ManualMigrations {
        val M_1_2 = object : Migration(1, 2) {
            override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE user ADD COLUMN height INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to deprecate **all** manual migration and use auto-migration instead. I change the code and got an error:

```kotlin
// Compile Time Error: 
// New NOT NULL column'height' added with no default value specified. 
// Please specify the default value using @ColumnInfo.
@Database(
    entities = [User::class],
    autoMigrations = [
        AutoMigration(from = 1, to = 2)
    ],
    version = 2
)
abstract class UserDB : RoomDatabase()
```

**even if I have specify default value by @ColumnInfo, but still got same error**:

```kotlin
// Compile Time Error: 
// New NOT NULL column'height' added with no default value specified. 
// Please specify the default value using @ColumnInfo.
@Entity(tableName = "user")
data class User(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    val id: Long = 0L,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    val name: String = "",
    // specify default value by this way
    @Column(name = "height", defaultValue = "0")
    val height: Long = 0L
)

@Database(
    entities = [User::class],
    autoMigrations = [
        AutoMigration(from = 1, to = 3)
    ],
    // Since I have modify the structure of table, 
    // I increase the version.
    version = 3
)
abstract class UserDB : RoomDatabase()
```

What wrong with my code and how can i fix this error?

## Update

I have modify the annotation of `height` field

from

```kotlin
@Column(name = "height", defaultValue = "0")
val height: Long = 0L
```

to

```kotlin
@ColumnInfo(name = "height", defaultValue = "0")
val height: Long = 0L
```

And follow above step but get a runtime exception

1. fully uninstall app, and install the app with database version = 1;
2. add new column height with annotation: `@ColumnInfo(name = "height")` and database version update to version 2 by writing manual migration. then run new version app;
3. to use auto-migration, I delete manual migration and update height field annotation: `@ColumnInfo(name = "height", defaultValue = "0")`
   (if I not specify default value, room compiler will tell me I must specify default value by throwing Exception during compile time) and increase version from 2 to 3, and specify autoMigrations into `@Database`:

```kotlin
@Database(
    entities = [Worker::class],
    autoMigrations = [AutoMigration(from = 1, to = 3)],
    version = 3
)
abstract class UserDB : RoomDatabase()
```

Then at runtime execute these code and got an runtime exception:

```kotlin
val userDB = buildUserDB().openHelper.readableDatabase
            Log.d(TAG, "columnNames=${workerDB.query("SELECT * FROM user").columnNames.toList()}")

// java.lang.IllegalStateException: A migration from 2 to 3 was required but not found. 
// Please provide the necessary Migration path via RoomDatabase.Builder.addMigration(Migration ...) 
// or allow for destructive migrations via one of the 
// RoomDatabase.Builder.fallbackToDestructiveMigration* methods.
```

Comment: You do have `exportSchema = true` as part of the @Database annotation (the code you have shown doesn't include this)?

Comment: @MikeT thanks for you reply.  `exportSchema` field is true by default.

Comment: Ooops always code it so forgot.

Answer (score 3):

> even if I have specify default value by @ColumnInfo, but still got same error:

I believe (according to the long version) that your issue is that you are using `@Column(....` instead of `@ColumnInfo(....`.

So change

```
@Column(name = "height", defaultValue = "0")
val height: Long = 0L
```

to

```
@ColumnInfo(name = "height", defaultValue = "0")
val height: Long = 0L
```

Testing the above  using two runs one at version 1 and then 2 (using corrected @ColumnInfo) using:-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var db: UserDB
    lateinit var dao: UserDao
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        db = UserDB.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getUserDao()

        dao.insert(User(name = "NAME001Version$DATABASE_VERSION"))
        dao.insert(User(name = "NAME002Version$DATABASE_VERSION"))
        dao.insert(User(name = "NAME003Version$DATABASE_VERSION"))

        for (u in dao.getAllUsers()) {
            Log.d("DBINFO","User ID = ${u.id} UserName is ${u.name} Version is ${DATABASE_VERSION}")
        }
    }
}
```

- Where DATABASE_VERSION is the version #

The DB via App inspection is :-

[image]

The logs from both runs :-

```
2022-05-24 19:32:57.784 D/DBINFO: User ID = 1 UserName is NAME001Version1 Version is 1
2022-05-24 19:32:57.784 D/DBINFO: User ID = 2 UserName is NAME002Version1 Version is 1
2022-05-24 19:32:57.784 D/DBINFO: User ID = 3 UserName is NAME003Version1 Version is 1



2022-05-24 19:38:41.963 D/DBINFO: User ID = 1 UserName is NAME001Version1 Version is 2
2022-05-24 19:38:41.963 D/DBINFO: User ID = 2 UserName is NAME002Version1 Version is 2
2022-05-24 19:38:41.964 D/DBINFO: User ID = 3 UserName is NAME003Version1 Version is 2
2022-05-24 19:38:41.964 D/DBINFO: User ID = 4 UserName is NAME001Version2 Version is 2
2022-05-24 19:38:41.964 D/DBINFO: User ID = 5 UserName is NAME002Version2 Version is 2
2022-05-24 19:38:41.964 D/DBINFO: User ID = 6 UserName is NAME003Version2 Version is 2
```

To replicate the issue (had to add a basic annotation for @Column) and then:-

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your patient response and sorry for slow response, I have modify the annotation from `@Column` to `@ColumnInfo` and then compile success. But at this time I query database at runtime exception that told me I have no specify the migration from 2 to 3. Could you help me to investigate this problem? many thanks and hope you have a nice day :) !

Comment: @ZSpirytus I believe that you need a 2 to 3 migration, 1-> 3 will only migrate if the old version is 1 and the new version is 2.

Answer (score 3):

I have found the root cause of this problem.

## Short Version

This exception is thrown when room compiler  generate `migration_1_2` by comparing 1.json(schema json file) with 2.json, not when generating `migration_5_6` or other migration.

The reason why this exception is thrown is that 1.json don't have height column while 2.json have nonNull height column but have no default value from `@ColumnInfo`.

Because modify 2.json (history schema json file) is dangerous, so I give up the idea of ​​replacing manual migrations with auto-migration.

## Long Version

Let me show a piece of code at **Room Compiler** to explain why this problem appear:

```kotlin
// SchemaDiffer.kt

class SchemaDiffer(...) {

    ...

    private fun processAddedTableAndColumns(...) {
        toColumns.values.forEach { toColumn ->
            val match = fromColumns[toColumn.columnName]
            if (match == null) {
                if (toColumn.isNonNull && toColumn.defaultValue == null) {
                    // >>>>>>> ** HERE! ** >>>>>>>
                    // New NOT NULL column'height' added with no default value specified.
                    diffError(
                        newNotNullColumnMustHaveDefaultValue(toColumn.columnName)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code tell me that Room Compiler will throw an exception if new column is nonNull **BUT** it has not being specified a default value when doing an **auto-migration** from an old database to new database.

Take a look on my requirement and my piece of code:

- I want to replace **ALL** manual migration with room auto-migration.

And my code:

```kotlin
// column declaration
// a non null type long
// and has not specified default value on @ColumnInfo
@ColumnInfo(name = "height")
val height: Long = 0L
```

When Room Compiler process **@ColumnInfo** annotate on `height` field to generate `migration_1_to_2`, it find that the `height` field it nonNull (by `XType.nullability`) and it has not specify default value (by reading `@ColumnInfo.defalutValue`).

Then, by comparing 1.json with 2.json, room compiler find that `height` is **NEW** column.

There is a contradiction: `height` column is nonNull but it has no default value! To let dev know this issue, room compiler choose to throw exception.

By analyze source code, we know that exception is thrown when room compiler generate `migration_1_to_2`, not when generating `migration_5_to_6` or other migration. So even if we specify a default for `height`, room compiler still throw this problem -- current version is 6, room compiler will generate 6.json, not 2.json, default specification is not written to 2.json.

I think modify a history schema json file is dangerous, so I give up the idea of ​​replacing manual migrations with auto-migration.